# Buildfire: Best way to allow user to upload photos

Tags: buildfire

Is there anything that is built into the Buildfire platform that would easily allow a user from the "Widget" to upload and post photos to the Buildfire server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this API.
https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/File-System-Services

Then you want to pass your image to the get Server / CDN using
https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-use-ImageLib#buildfireimagelibcropimageurl-options-cdn-mode

*Keep in mind usage is limited to your app tier*